# How to prevent EF Core from making an incorrect join between entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I need to somehow either explicitly ignore a "deep" navigational property of a complex type or explicitly tell EF how to join

I am doing a simple select of users and mapping to a flat viewmodel (I have obviously setup relevant mappings for the ProjectTo):

```
return await DataContext.Users
    .ProjectTo<UserModel>()
    .ToListAsync();

public class User {
    public int PersonId { get; set; }       
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public int DeptartmentId { get; set; }      
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
public class Department {
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public int DeptartmentHeadId { get; set; }      
    public Person DepartmentHead { get; set; }
}
public class UserSummary
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

overriding the OnModelCreating method like this works for this scenario, but obviously will exclude OwnerPerson all the time, we only want to exclude
it when selecting User entity from the DB and mapping it to UserModel:

```
builder.Entity<Department>().Ignore(x => x.DepartmentHead);
```

I need to do something like:

```
builder.Entity<User>().Ignore(x => x.Person.Department.DepartmentHead);
```

Using SQL Profiler you can see it creates an unexpected join on departments:

```
 SELECT * FROM [Users] AS [x] 
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[People] AS [x.Person]
 ON [x].[PersonId] = [x.Person].[Id] 
 LEFT JOIN [Departments] AS [x.Person.Department] 
 ON [x.Person].[Id] = [x.Person.Department].[DeptartmentHeadId]
```

What I want is:

```
 SELECT * FROM [Users] AS [x] 
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[People] AS [x.Person]
 ON [x].[PersonId] = [x.Person].[Id] 
 LEFT JOIN [Departments] AS[x.Person.Department] 
 ON [x.Person].[DepartmentId] = [x.Person.Department].[Id]
```

Comment: This looks like incorrect relationship mapping. Can we see the fluent configuration?

Comment: @IvanStoev - Thank you for the comment, made me realize how to resolve... See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I needed to do was tell EF that a Department has people (therefore fixing relationship mapping):

```
public class Department {
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public int DeptartmentHeadId { get; set; }      
    public Person DepartmentHead { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Person.Department))]
    public IList<Person> People { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
}
```